# How to display calls name along with the Summary on JMeter Console during the test execution in non GUI

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

Is there any way to display more info on the JMeter console during the test execution in non-GUI mode.

I would like to see the calls names next to the summary so I can know exactly what call has failed while running the test in **non-GUI mode**.
The idea behind is to stop the test the moment I see the error and easy way to debug and identify the call.

For ex: one of the call name of script from the below screenshot is `"SupportUnemploymentRequest_PJLReport_28_SOAPAction_RptReportProvider_GetReportWsDtoDataSetBytes"`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You have "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" setting in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) which defaults to `Continue`. Just change it to `Stop` and JMeter will automatically finish your test on first sampler failure.

   [image: JMeter Thread Group Stop test]
2. Alternative option would be adding a [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) which would print current URL to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) for information purposes and stop the test in case of failure. Example reference code would be something like:

   ```
   def success = SampleResult.isSuccessful() 
   println('Processing URL: ' + SampleResult.getUrlAsString() + '. Successful: ' + success)

   if (!success) {
       println('Failure, stopping test')   
       SampleResult.setStopTest(true)  
   }
   ```

Check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more information on 2nd approach.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri,but let me put it this way basically I would like to see all the steps irrespective of  error and success.User who ever executing the test they should able to monitor and should able to watch on which step the test is at.-Raj